# Desire2Learn SSO to Learning object page

Tags: desire2learn

I can use the SSO to D2L to go to the Home page or to the course home page if i supply the orgid as a query param. How can I go to other areas like course content, LO or user progress, gradebook using the SSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the vintage of the LMS you're using; some pages hosted by the LMS support the deep-linking required to directly visit the page, and some do not. There is an effort by D2L to move more and more pages to the new framework that supports deep-linking, so each release *should* have more pages eligible for this behaviour. If you have pages in particular you'd like to see support this behaviour, you can provide this feedback through your account manager: D2L prioritizes work in consideration of customer demand, so letting them now might help.

Comment: @Victor thanks for your answer. But can you explain a little bit more about how it will work as the for SSO we need to go to the URL http://d2lurl/d2l/lp/auth/ssologin.d2l. In case of accessing other areas will the URL will be different or we need to pass some other parameter to indicate I want to go to another deep linked page.

Comment: Update: I can redirect myself from the SSOLogin page to User Progress / Gradebook page - if I add a request parameter "target="<destination URL>"" - is that a reliable method?

Comment: Yes, the general technique is to pass the desired target page through on the 'target=<desination URL>', and that is the reliable and approved method. Pages that support that technique now will continue to; however, not all LMS pages support that technique, depending upon which version of the LMS you have. Newer versions of the LMS will likely add more support for deeplinking to more non-home-page areas, but they likely won't remove such support. (Although they may move functionality from one URL to another: the technique is sound, individual static URL forms may not be.)